# How can I prevent =FILTER to become {=FILTER}

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula

So I am trying to create a table that auto updates when an items is introduce in another for this I am trying to use filter function to update the table if a value has a certain value. For exemple:

| Item | Price | Where |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 15 | Market |
| B | 17 | In person |
| C | 1 | Market |
| D | 9 | Market |

And the table that I want to get is when Where is equal to Market so

| Item | Price | Where |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 15 | Market |
| C | 1 | Market |
| D | 9 | Market |

For this I am using the =FILTER but my problem is that I have a python script to update the values from the table and when it runs the filter function becomes {=FILTER(...)} and if I change the value Where from A to In person I returns #N/A on every field in the updated table.
Is there anything to prevent that this filter function becomes {=FILTER} ?

```
def updateCell(celIdx,value):
sheet[celIdx] = value
try:
    workbook.save("Warframe.xlsx")
    print("Values updated")
except:
    print("File is open. Close it and run again")
```

this is where I update the value it updates but when chage the where it does what I said above

Comment: It is hard to identify your problem without a Minimal Reproducible Example (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  As a complete aside, note it is dangerous to assume you know the only reason that an exception could be raised and make a blanket `except` which completely ignores the content of the  raised exception.

Comment: I suggest the MRE because I can assign a "=FILTER(...)" to a cell using openpyxl with no problem.  So, the problem is likely in what you are passing in as the `value`, and without seeing how you are setting `value` it is impossible to provide any help.